# How to store a facebook graph api response of users friends connections to a variable or array to use later using using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the facebook Javascript SDK to login to my site and also capture information about the users friends.

The below code block checks the user is logged in and then in an array captures the users friends details.

What I dont understand at the moment is if the array the data is stored in exists? how can I add the friends data to an array that I can later pass to my db? also how can I look at the data again using chrome inspector? would i do a console log to see the object?

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response){
      if (response && response.data){
        console.log('Success', response);



      } else {
        console.log('Something goes wrong', response);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: You can use [`jQuery.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Comment: Thanks, would you mind explaining how I'd use that? from teh above I'm not sure what name to parse in?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response){
      if (response && response.data){
        var contact = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
        var fbdata=response.data;
        var divTarget=document.getElementById("friends-list-container");
      for (var friendIndex=0; friendIndex<fbdata.length; friendIndex++)
    {      var divContainer = document.createElement("div");
           divContainer.innerHTML="<b>" + fbdata[friendIndex].name + "</b>";
           divTarget.appendChild(divContainer);
    }
```